# Как правильно "готовить" авторизацию в SPA?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, oauth, jwt

Цель такая: написать **бэкенд** ASP.Net Core MVC* SPA для работы с ReactJS и дальнейшей возможностью переиспользовать существующий API для создания, скажем, Android приложения. 
 
Платформа: `.Net Core 2.1`.

* - *Если такое ещё можно назвать MVC, учитывая, что View не будет, а будет отдельная директория* `ClientApp` *со всем содержимым фронтэнда.*

Пошуршав интернеты, наткнулся на то, что ASP.Net Core Identity не актуален. Звучит логично, учитывая, что тот сильно опирается на куки, а при общении через API куки таскать неудобно. Хотя многие примеры нижеупомянутого JWT всё же используют `IdentityUser`.

Много инструкций с использованием JWT. Приличная часть из них слишком зациклена на фронтенд реализации и практически ничего не говорит о бэкенде. Не нашёл примеров с OAuth2, везде свой велосипед, причём Demo и не пригодный для реального использования. 
В тех же примерах по JWT используются `Issuer`, `Audience` и `SecretKey`, но ни слова о том, по каким правилам их надо выбирать и/или генерировать, ну и где безопасно хранить (если исключить примеры с хардкодом, то их обычно хранили в `appsettings.json`).

Также в процессе гугления (конкретно: попытке найти инфу об `JwtSecurityTokenHandler` из `System.IdentityModel.Tokens`) MSDN Microsoft выдаёт:

> We’re no longer updating this content regularly. Check the Microsoft Product Lifecycle for information about how this product, service, or technology is supported.

Что это значит? Microsoft более не поддерживает JWT? Технология в принципе уже неактуальна? Что же тогда использовать?

В итоге мне теперь не совсем понятно как строить авторизацию в своём приложении:

- Нужные ли мне `IdentityUser` из `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity`?
- Нужен ли мне `IdentityDbContext` из `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore`?
- Актуален ли JWT?
- Как построить авторизацию с OAuth2?

Хотелось бы сохранить доступность авторизованного пользователя из `HttpContext.User` и к его `Claims`, чтобы не мучать БД лишний раз для получения Id/UserName/Avatar/LastOnline/etc.

А также учесть то, что активно будут использоваться роли пользователей.

**UPD:** Немного обновлю конечные цели, чтобы стало понятнее:

- Это форум с разделами, постами и комментариями в формате вопрос-ответ
- Реализация фронтенда через SPA
- Планируется открытое API
- Это же API будет использовать SPA
- Поддержка быстрой регистрации/входа через сторонние сервисы (Vk, FB, Google, etc.)

Comment: Не могу предоставить никаких подробностей, но сколько я могу судить, нужно использовать IdentityServer: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4, который будет работать как авторизационный сервер и выдавать соответствующие токены и пр.

Comment: Microsoft прекратили поддержку не JWT, а старой документации. Придется дождаться пока ссылки на нее пропадут из гугла прежде чем удастся хоть что-нибудь прочитать там...

Comment: Посмотрите их примеры: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Вот проверенный код, который работает. 
Итак, настройка аутентификации в Startup

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);

        services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>                  
                options.UseMySql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>();          

        services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
        {
            //........
        });         


        services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    // укзывает, будет ли валидироваться издатель при валидации токена
                    ValidateIssuer = false, 
                    // будет ли валидироваться потребитель токена
                    ValidateAudience = false,                       
                    // будет ли валидироваться время существования
                    ValidateLifetime = true,

                    // установка ключа безопасности
                    IssuerSigningKey = AuthOptions.GetSymmetricSecurityKey(),
                    // валидация ключа безопасности
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                };
            });

        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                .Build();
        });

        // .........            
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        // ...............      
        app.UseAuthentication();
        // ................
    }
}
```

Класс AuthOptions

```
public class AuthOptions
{
    const string KEY = "mysupersecret_secretkey!";   // ключ для шифрации
    public const int LIFETIME = 300; // время жизни токена - 5 часов
    public static SymmetricSecurityKey GetSymmetricSecurityKey()
    {
        return new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(KEY));
    }
}
```

Моделька для запроса токена

```
public class TokenRequest
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Контроллер для получения токена

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;

    public AccountController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _signInManager = signInManager;
    }

    [HttpPost("[action]")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Auth([FromBody] TokenRequest tokenRequest)
    {
        var username = tokenRequest.UserName;
        var password = tokenRequest.Password;            

        var principal = await GetPrincipal(username, password);
        if (principal == null)
        {   
            return StatusCode(400, "Invalid username or password.");
        }

        var now = DateTime.UtcNow;
        // создаем JWT-токен
        var jwt = new JwtSecurityToken(                    
                notBefore: now,
                claims: principal.Claims,
                expires: now.Add(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(AuthOptions.LIFETIME)),
                signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(AuthOptions.GetSymmetricSecurityKey(), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256));
        var encodedJwt = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(jwt);

        var response = new
        {
            token = encodedJwt,
            username = principal.Identity.Name
        };

        return Json(response);           
    }

    private async Task<ClaimsPrincipal> GetPrincipal(string username, string password)
    {
        var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(username);
        if (user != null)
        {
            var check = await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, password);
            if (check)
            {
                var principal = await  _signInManager.CreateUserPrincipalAsync(user);
                return principal;                                        
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

И, по моему, это все. С этим все остальные вещи типа атрибутов авторизации, роли и прочее работает из коробки. Насколько я помню, ничего дополнительно делать не надо.

---

**UPD**

При переходе на core 3.0 понадобятся дополнительные пакеты, см. [Как заменить расширение AddJwtBearer при переходе на .NET Core 3.0](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1136902/179763)

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79951/discussion-on-answer-by-tym32167------spa).

Comment: @ЮрийСПб ну и зачем вы переместили в чат важные замечания по ответу?

Comment: Замечания: 1. Issuer и Audience в условиях одного сайта проверять не надо, достаточно проверить ключ (см. мой ответ).
2. Работать с Response в контроллере - зачем?! return Json(response) теперь запретили или как?

Comment: 3. метод GetIdentity частично дублирует то, что делает метод CreateUserPrincipalAsync. Всю работу с клаймами можно делегировать последнему.

Comment: 4. ConfigureApplicationCookie не нужен!

Comment: @PavelMayorov  я думал, вы поправите мой ответ :) Если не забуду, вечером поправлю что смогу сам.

Comment: @tym32167 да говорю же, мне нечем его скомпилировать. Сижу на 2015й студии все еще.

Comment: @PavelMayorov у меня на работе тоже 2015, я себе дома поставил потыкать в это палкой :)

Comment: @tym32167 не знаю как у вас, но у меня уже глубокая ночь. 
Напоминаю вам. Очень нужны правки! В комментариях уже запутался.

Comment: @adrug я прямо в данный момент редактирую ответ, потерпите :)

Comment: @PavelMayorov обновил ответ, компилируется, благополучно работает. Спасибо за замечания и правки

Comment: @adrug готово, можно глядеть

Comment: @tym32167 Пытался сегодня реализовать подобное, JWT авторизация работает на ура, а вот стандартная через Cookie (на чистом проекте) на прочь отрубается. Я так понимаю, что идет некая замена авторизации по Cookie, но как их заставить работать вместе? Добавил `.AddCookie(cfg => cfg.SlidingExpiration = true)`, сами Cookie заработали, да вот все страницы с `[Authorize]` пишут 401. Получается надо еще добавить что то в `services.AddAuthorization`, но что?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ я не пробовал, но вот [тут](https://wildermuth.com/2017/08/19/Two-AuthorizationSchemes-in-ASP-NET-Core-2) пишут, что атрибут авторизации по умолчанию использует только одну схему. То есть вам надо ему обе схемы в параметрах передать

Comment: @tym32167 Пробовал тот вариант, игрался с аттрибутами, пробовал разные подходы но все не как не пускает, 401, либо страница авторизации. Ладно, пойду дальше искать решения...

Comment: @tym32167 А как тут в плане безопасности? Достаточно ли этого всего для простого приложения с выводом информации о личных данных пользователя (и изменение некоторых его данных) , либо же надо что то еще внедрять?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ То, что описано выше - кусок моего хобби проекта, где я вообще не заморачивался безопасностью. Это самая простая схема с одним токеном. По идее в идеале должно быть 2 токена - основной и токен продления. Токен продления должен быть одноразовый. Генерация нового токена продления должна убивать все текущие  токены, оставляя только вновь созданный. Но это я где то в сети читал, сам не очень исследовал этот вопрос.

Comment: При переходе на core 3.0 понадобятся дополнительные пакеты, см. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1136902/213987

Comment: @AK добавил апдейт

Answer (score 8):

Для начала, ASP.Net Core Identity никаким образом не опирается на куки! ASP.Net Core Identity - это прежде всего система для хранения и обработки информации о пользователях.

Все что делает Identity во время аутентификации - это загружает из БД информацию о пользователе, заполняя набор утверждений о нем, после чего передает его ASP.NET Core.

Соответственно, нет никакого смысла искать как использовать ASP.Net Core Identity вместе с Jwt - это попросту не связанные друг с другом вещи.

---

Теперь про OAuth. Технология OAuth предназначена для того, чтобы *сторонний* разработчик мог создать приложение которое бы работало с вашим сайтом, но при этом не имел доступа к паролям ваших пользователей. Если же вы собрались создавать приложение на Андроиде самостоятельно - использование OAuth будет для вас избыточно!

Все что вам нужно - это action в контроллере, который принимает логин с паролем и выдает токен.

Ну а если вы решили дать доступ к своему API именно для сторонних разработчиков - [Identity Server](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4) вам в помощь.

---

Наконец, про JWT.

`Audience` - это параметр токена, который означает целевую систему куда его можно предъявлять. Иными словами, это URL вашего сайта. Однако, нет никакого смысла в его использовании в ситуации когда у вас только один сайт: он нужен когда есть несколько сайтов со своими API и эти сайты не доверяют друг другу.

`Issuer` - это URI провайдера, который выдал JWT. То есть, опять-таки, URL вашего сайта. Это поле используется только в тех случаях когда доступ к API можно получить при помощи токенов от разных поставщиков. В остальных случаях это поле вообще-то не обязательное.

`SecretKey` - это, скорее всего, ключ, которым вы шифруете или подписываете JWT. Хранить его можно в appsettings.json или в переменных окружения. Главное - не публикуйте его на github. Вообще, желательно использовать разные ключи для разработки и на "боевом" сервере.

Comment: думаю, автор вопроса искал пример кода, так как ваш ответ по идее и так очевиден. Я так подумал, так как сам когда то делал jwt в asp.net core и найти информацию сходу было проблематично, потратил час где то на гугление - поиск

Comment: @tym32167 ну, если у вас есть пример кода - можете привести его.

Comment: Обновил цели проекта, чтобы стало яснее, что мне требуется

Comment: добавил ответом

Answer (score 2):

Отталкивался я от ответа @tym32167 (поэтому и пометил его как правильный), но на всякий случай добавлю конкретно свою реализацию. Вдруг будет кому-то полезна.

Startup.cs

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // подключение DbContext'ов

        // подключение Identity

        services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
        {
            // ...
        });

        // игнорирование регистра (url без заглавных букв)
        services.Configure<RouteOptions>(options => options.LowercaseUrls = true);

        // подключение репозиториев

        services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    //ValidIssuer = "",

                    ValidateAudience = false,
                    //ValidAudience = "",

                    ValidateLifetime = true,

                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Configuration["Jwt:Key"])),
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                };
            });

        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                .Build();
        });

        services.AddMvc()
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

        services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
        {
            configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/build";
        });
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error"); //ToDo: do it better
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

        app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                // актуально для ReactJS
                spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

appsettings.json

```
{
  "Jwt": {
    "Key": "my_very_secret_key",
    "LifeTime": "300"
  }
}
```

`Jwt:Key` должен быть больше 16 символов (128 бит) иначе выбрасывает исключение при генерации токена. По крайней мере, при использовании шифрования HmacSha256.

TokenRequest.cs

```
public class TokenRequest
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "")]
    [JsonProperty("login")]
    public string Login { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [JsonProperty("password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

RegisterModel.cs

```
public class RegisterModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "")]
    [JsonProperty("username")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "")]
    [EmailAddress]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [JsonProperty("email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [JsonProperty("password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "")]
    [JsonProperty("confirm_password")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

AccountController.cs

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class AccountController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly UserManager<UserAccount> userManager;
    private readonly SignInManager<UserAccount> signInManager;
    private readonly IConfiguration configuration;

    public AccountController(
        UserManager<UserAccount> userManager,
        SignInManager<UserAccount> signInManager,
        IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        this.userManager = userManager;
        this.signInManager = signInManager;
        this.configuration = configuration;
    }

    [HttpPost("[action]")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Register([FromBody] RegisterModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var errors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors.Select(e => e.ErrorMessage));
            return BadRequest(errors);
        }

        var userAccount = new UserAccount { Email = model.Email, UserName = model.UserName };
        var result = await userManager.CreateAsync(userAccount, model.Password);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            var token = await GetTokenAsync(userAccount);

            return Ok(new { token });
        }

        return BadRequest(result.Errors.Select(e => e.Description));
    }

    [HttpPost("[action]")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Auth([FromBody] TokenRequest tokenRequest)
    {
        var userAccount = tokenRequest.Login.Contains('@') ?
            await userManager.FindByEmailAsync(tokenRequest.Login) :
            await userManager.FindByNameAsync(tokenRequest.Login);

        if (userAccount == null)
        {
            return NotFound(new { message = $"User with login {tokenRequest.Login} not found!" });
        }

        var passValided = await userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(userAccount, tokenRequest.Password);

        if (!passValided)
        {
            return UnprocessableEntity(new { message = "Invalid username or password." });
        }

        var token = await GetTokenAsync(userAccount);

        return Ok(token); 
    }

    private async Task<string> GetTokenAsync(UserAccount userAccount)
    {
        var principal = await signInManager.CreateUserPrincipalAsync(userAccount);

        var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)principal.Identity;

        if (identity == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var now = DateTime.UtcNow;
        // created JWT-token
        var jwt = new JwtSecurityToken(
                notBefore: DateTime.UtcNow,
                claims: identity.Claims,
                expires: now.Add(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(int.Parse(configuration["Jwt:LifeTime"]))),
                signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(
                    new SymmetricSecurityKey(
                        Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(configuration["Jwt:Key"])),
                    SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256));

        var token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(jwt);

        return token;
    }
}
```

`UserAccount` наследник `IdentityUser`, а `UserRole` наследник `IdentityRole`