# RefreshToken в JWT

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, oauth, jwt

По ответам из [этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/851781/) вопроса я понял как создавать jwt токен. Но теперь встал вопрос, как его неявно обновлять. Можно использовать `refresh_token`, но в обычном варианте он будет меняться при каждом логине пользователя. Т.е.:

- Пользователь ввёл логин и пароль с одного устройства (например, браузер на ПК)
- Получил токен и рефреш
- Пользователь ввёл логин и пароль на другом устройстве (например, браузер на телефоне)
- Пользователь получил новые токен и рефреш
- Старые стали невалидны
- Пользователю требуется логиниться заново на первом устройстве

Как итог у пользователя в принципе нет возможности быть авторизованным на двух устройствах одновременно.

В голову пришла мысль хранить в БД помимо самого рефреша и его срока годности ещё и какой-нибудь `device_id`, но что может быть этим `device_id`? User-Agent? Но он вроде не уникален.

Как лучше всего реализовать авторизацию на нескольких устройствах одновременно?

Вполне возможно я зря тут пытаюсь городить свой велосипед и у JWT есть готовое решение для этого, если так, то буду рад узнать о нём. (Мне, по крайней мере, гугл выдаёт лишь разного рода собственные реализации, причём без учёта нескольких девайсов)

Comment: Возможно стоит посмотреть в сторону сессии. Одна авторизация - одна сессия.

Comment: @DenisBubnov, я пытаюсь реализовать подход REST API, так что какие-то эксклюзивные фишки браузера, которые усложнят доступ через гипотетическое мобильное приложение, не хотелось бы использовать. Иначе бы в JWT в принципе было бы мало смысла. Меня бы устроила стандартная авторизация через куки)

Comment: `Старые стали невалидны` почему это? Что мешает запоминать каждый рефреш токен, что был выдан? 1) юзер ввел данные на устройстве А. Он не парится что там было на других устройствах. Все токены, выданные до этого, но ещё не истекшие по времени, также продолжают работать. Все одноразовые рефреш токены, что ещё не истекли и не были использованы - продолжают работать.

Comment: @tym32167, ну я натыкался на мнение, что это "тру вей", ибо если рефреш токен будет скомпрометирован, то если третья сторона воспользовалась им и обновила токен, то пользователь потеряет доступ и авторизуется снова, тем самым сделав невалидными скомпрометированный рефреш

Comment: @tym32167, хотя.. если у меня обычный форум без каких-то особо секьюрных данных, можно оставить всё как вы предложили, но добавить возможность пользователю видеть в профиле все активные авторизации (рефреш-токены) и возможность досрочно отозвать любой из них или сразу все. К примеру, если он заметил подозрительную активность со своего профиля.

Comment: Если вы хотите заморочиться, то тогда вам надо 2факторную аутентификацию и список доверенных устройств. Но это все от ваших хотелок, конечно, зависит :) Ну, или хотя бы запоминайте устройство, которому был выдан рефреш токен, и что токен будет валиден только для этого устройства и при перелогине с этого устройства все предыдущие токены этого устройства умирают

Comment: @tym32167, `запоминайте устройство, которому был выдан рефреш токен` - как раз в этом и заключался изначально вопрос) как мне запоминать устройство, чтобы в дальнейшем его можно было распознать?

Comment: Если бы я знал, то уже бы написал ответ. Мне кажется тут надо все, и IP, и юзер агент, и МАС, и все, что можно, передавать, ну и что то наверняка надо сгенерить, что-то вроде ключа. Но это не точно :)

Comment: @tym32167, ясно,. спасибо. тогда не буду городить оверхед. буду запоминать токены и удалять только при запросе рефреша или истечения срока. при повторной авторизации буду просто выдавать новый)

Comment: Дельная мысль. Я вот, например, настолько ленив, что у меня в пет проекте вообще нет рефреш токенов :)

Comment: @tym32167, повторный ввод логина/пароля каждый 15 минут как-то слишком всё же :)

Comment: ну у меня сервис только для своих, на ограниченный круг людей, которые даже если захотят, то ничего не испортят, потому у меня токены на 5 часов