# WebAPI Core 2.1 Аутентификация

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, auth, azure

Как можно проводить проверку пользователя в WebAPI? Насколько я понимаю, надо передавать токен в авторизации в заголовке при каждом обращении. Но как его проверять? Есть ли какие пользовательские решения(как микросервис для авторизации и проверки) или надо использовать Azur AD 2BC(который кстати не совсем гладко работает с Core 2.1)? Может кто-то уже делал авторизацию в микросервисной архитектуре?

Comment: Я думаю тебе подойдет аутентификация через [JWT](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/851781/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%B2-spa)

Comment: Да, наверняка. Я сейчас выбрал Azure AD b2c, но везде есть свои нюансы. Спасибо за ссылку.