# Получение JWT токена с включенной 2fa

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt

Господа, пытаюсь сделать получение JWT токена на аккаунте с включенным Two-factor authentication (2fa). Как я это сделал:

1. Отправляем POST запрос с JSON телом, которое содержит логин и пароль.
2. Вызываем `signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync`, который выдает нам `SignInResult`.
3. Проверяем `SignInResult`:

   - если это `Succeeded` - генерируем токен.
   - если это `RequiresTwoFactor` - проверяем наличие ключа в запросе, если он есть - пробуем авторизоваться, нет - ошибка.
4. Выводим токен.

Действия при `RequiresTwoFactor`:

1. Выполняем `signInManager.GetTwoFactorAuthenticationUserAsync();`
2. Далее выполняем `signInManager.TwoFactorAuthenticatorSignInAsync(authenticatorCode, false, false)`, который также дает нам статус.
3. Если `Succeeded`, то генерируем токен и отдаем.

Сам код пока имеет такой набросок:

```
[HttpPost("[action]/{key?}")]
public async Task<ActionResult> Auth([FromBody] TokenRequest tokenRequest, string key)
{
    if (tokenRequest == null)
        return StatusCode(400, "Request cannot be null!");

    var username = tokenRequest.UserName;
    var password = tokenRequest.Password;

    var result = await signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(username, password, false, lockoutOnFailure: true);

    if (result.Succeeded)
    {
        var user = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(username);
        if (user != null)
        {
            var principal = await signInManager.CreateUserPrincipalAsync(user);
            var token = GenerateToken(principal);

            var response = new
            {
                token,
                principal.Identity.Name
            };

            return Json(response);
        }
    }

    if (result.IsLockedOut)
    {
        return StatusCode(423, "Account locked out!");
    }

    if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
    {
        if (key == null)
            return StatusCode(400, "Two-factor authentication `key` needed!");

        var user = await signInManager.GetTwoFactorAuthenticationUserAsync();
        if (user == null)
            return StatusCode(502, "Unable to load two-factor authentication user.");

        var authenticatorCode = key.Replace(" ", string.Empty).Replace("-", string.Empty);
        var authResult = await signInManager.TwoFactorAuthenticatorSignInAsync(authenticatorCode, false, false);

        if (authResult.Succeeded)
        {
            var principal = await signInManager.CreateUserPrincipalAsync(user);
            var token = GenerateToken(principal);

            var response = new
            {
                token,
                principal.Identity.Name
            };

            return Json(response);
        }
        else if (authResult.IsLockedOut)
        {
            return StatusCode(423, "Account locked out!");
        }
        else
        {
            return StatusCode(400, "Invalid authenticator code.");
        }
    }
    return StatusCode(400, "Login Failed!");
}
```

Все это вроде как работает, но вот одна загвоздка - тут используются Cookie, а точнее:

- В момент первой авторизации нам вешает куку `Identity.TwoFactorUserId` с неким ключом и дает сообщение "Требуется 2fa код".
- Далее как я понял, мы через `signInManager.GetTwoFactorAuthenticationUserAsync();` эту куку считываем, а также код присланный вторым запросом и сверяем все это.

**Вопрос:**
Как мне грамотно реализовать авторизацию с 2fa, не используя куки, ведь в API не очень хорошо (да и не очень удобно) использовать куки, или ошибаюсь?

*За основу взял [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/852085/220553) ответ.*

---

**Для чего это:**

Делаю сайт на ASP.Net Core 2.1, который будет неким центральным хабом (аккаунт с возможностью управления, магазин, взаимодействие с игровым миром (сервер будет выдавать свое API для этого, сайт здесь будет в роли клиента).

Для этого всего требуется еще реализовать клиентское приложение, которое сейчас разрабатывается на WPF (его задачи: информация об аккаунте, балансе пользователя, информация о персонажах, обновление клиента и др. информация). По сути это клиентское приложение, которое будет выводить информацию, с минимальным набором "изменяемых" API (то есть не будет пополнение счета через него, не будет изменение пароля и др.). Вот в нем требуется узнать пользователя, авторизовать его, получить его информацию и в дальнейшем пустить в игру.

Comment: 3 года прошло, когда сохранил вопрос на будущее. Будущее наступило, мне тоже нужно к jwt  реализовать 2FA. Все вроде сделал, но застрял на моменте, когда эту 2FA первоначально настраиваешь, каждый следующей запрос уже просит 2FA claim и меня фактически выбрасывает на страницу логину из-за 401.

Comment: А нельзя выпустить специальный JWT - в котором будет закодирована роль `PENDING_TWO_FACTOR`? Этот JWT будет давать только право на прохождение 2FA, и будет означать лишь то, что его владелец правильно ввел логин  пароль. После прохождения 2FA, выпускается новый JWT, с уже стандартным набором ролей? Как тут - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73666299/is-it-secure-to-use-jwt-payload-for-some-authorization

Answer (score 1):

У меня была подобная проблема и решил её следующим способом:

```
var authenticatorCode = 
    model.TwoFactorCode.Replace(" ", string.Empty).Replace("-", string.Empty);

var is2faTokenValid = await _userManager.VerifyTwoFactorTokenAsync(
    user, _userManager.Options.Tokens.AuthenticatorTokenProvider, authenticatorCode
);
```

Comment: Интересное решение, но в таком случае я теряю LockedOut...