# Аутентификация ASP CORE WEB API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Всем привет! Тема давно не новая, но может кто-нибудь пришлет ссылки на примеры с грамотной реализацией аутентификации в ASP core на JWT-токенах? В сети много примитивных примеров, но они очень урезаны. Хочу понять как правильно реализуется аутентификация.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как правильно "готовить" авторизацию в SPA?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/851781/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%b2-spa)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, из-за отсутствия рефреш-токена тот пример тоже урезанный по сути...

Comment: Именно. По кусочкам собирать инфу приходится.

Comment: @4per Он не всегда нужен, ну а если понять суть, то сделать его довольно просто самостоятельно. Если расписывать все про JWT, то это как по мне получится огромная статья. Если взять конкретно данный вопрос, то в нем спрашивают "Как сделать аутентификацию средствами JWT", а про это сказано в дубликате, отмеченном мною. Допустим есть такая вещь, как 2FA, тоже весьма обширная тема, что и про нее будем писать здесь? Она ведь тоже относится к JWT авторизации. Я однажды [задавал вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/879786) можете заметить, что кода прилично. Так что лепить в одно место все - бред.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, а в каких случаях он нужен или не нужен? в целом вы правы, такой объём ответа, явно не формат для SO

Comment: @4per Все зависит от проекта. Если это небольшой сайт, который дает например просто набор данных (некий ReadOnly доступ), то зачем там Refresh токен? Я недавно познакомился с AppCenter от Microsoft, там есть возможность выложить версию приложения для каждого отдельного человека/группы, либо вовсе публичный. Для определения, какие пользователю доступны релизы есть система API ключей, они живут по сути вечно и в большом случае имеют ReadOnly права доступа, человек не может с таким ключом извинить например свой ник. Refresh это некий механизм защиты, чтобы не передавать постоянно логин и пароль.