# ASP.NET Identity (Vue.Js)

Tags: c#, asp.net, vue.js, .net-core

Всем привет. Пишу SPA-приложение на Vue.JS. Создал регистрацию и вход *через запрос Axios* (аналогично AJAX-запросу).
Ранее писал приложения без фреймворков. Аутентификация проходила успешно.

Возникла проблема. После отправки запроса **пользователь добавляется в БД, но куки не записываются.** Можно ли как-то записать их самому? И как без Razor Pages можно определить, авторизирован ли пользователь или нет? Я так понимаю, тоже с запросом?
Но все же хотелось бы распознавать это на стороне клиента.

Для авторизации использую SignInManager.

Заранее благодарен.

Comment: почему вы выбрали аутентификацмю по кукам для SPA приложения?

Comment: А что есть другой способ? Если вы имеете ввиду JWT, то смысл его использовать, если SignInManager и так создает токен. Но в моем случае пользователь все равно остается не авторизированным.

Comment: мне не поянтны ваши аргументы в пользу куков. Ну, создает что то там этот SignInManager, что с того? Пусть себе создает, это никак к вопросу не относится. Я юзал аутенификацию JWT, всё работает, никаких проблем.

Comment: Не понял, вы хотите сказать, что cookie, созданные SignInManager, не относятся к авторизации? А для чего тогда они вообще создаются? И еще, то есть для SPA приложения нужен именно JWT?

Comment: Вы меня не поняли. У меня есть хобби проект, он был сначала на angular+asp.net core, потом я фронт переписал на React - то есть у меня аж 2 варианта SPA. Когда я выбирал, как мне аутентифицироваться, я не хотел привязываться к кукам, так как я хотел иметь возможность вызывать свой API хоть откуда без танцев с куками. Таким образом, сейчас при авторизации у меня сервер на фронт присылает токен, который я добавляю в настройки axios и все остальные запросы на сервер в заголовках содержат токен. Мне эта схема проще показалась, чем передавать куки,потому я и спросил,почему вы выбрали куки,а не JWT?

Comment: Теперь понятно. Я выбрал куки, т.к. этот вариант мне казался проще.

Comment: Я знаю, что существуют IdentityServer, OpenId. Но я пока что не разбираюсь в них.

Comment: Я впервые связываю ASP.NET Identity с SPA. Если не трудно, вы можете дать ссылку, по которой вы смотрели, как связать JWT c ASP.NET Identity? Или вы без документации писали?

Comment: Я делал самую простую схему, с одним токеном, всё, что для этого надо, я [описал тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/852085/179763), там чисто генерация и проверка токена, никаких IdentityServer мне юзать не пришлось.

Comment: OK. Спасибо большое. Рад был услышать ваш ответ.

Comment: Буду использовать JWT.