# JWT ASP.Net Core Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi

я знакомлюсь с Jason Web Tokens и не могу найти толковую литературу, которая помогла бы мне в этом. Был бы невероятно признателен, если бы таковую кто то скинул!

Comment: [Как правильно “готовить” авторизацию в SPA?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/851781/179763)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как правильно "готовить" авторизацию в SPA?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/851781/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%b2-spa)