# Как подебажить аутентификацию на ASP?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, аутентификация

Пытаюсь настроить JWT аутентификацию на Asp .Net Core.
Сам JWT генерирует сторонний сервис, ключ от него у меня есть и я его проверял на jwt.io все ок совпадает.

Выставил все настройки по дефолту:

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IHostingEnvironment env) {
    ...
    app.UseAuthentication();
    ...
}
```

```cs
services
    .AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(cfg => {
        cfg.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        cfg.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters {
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(signingSecurityKey)),
        };
    });

services.AddAuthorization(options => {
    options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
    .Build();
});
```

Вот метод контроллера:

```cs
[Authorize]
[HttpGet, Route("hello")]
public string Hello() {

    return "Hello";
}
```

Получаю ошибку HTTP 401 Unauthorized.

А если изменить атрибут у метода на такой:

```cs
[Authorize(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
```

то получаю ошибку при обращении к нему:

```
InvalidOperationException: The AuthorizationPolicy named: 'Bearer' was not found
```

Никакого кода кроме приведенного я не писал. Может надо создать класс с описанием пользователя и как то его связать с авторизацией?

Comment: а в запросе токен как передаете?

Comment: в запросе токен передаю в header: authorization: Bearer <token>

Comment: Вы путаете аутентификацию и авторизацию. Настроек авторизации я у вас не вижу `services.AddAuthorization` [отсюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/852085/179763)

Comment: @tym32167 да вы правы, исправил название темы. И тем не менее как понять что именно у меня не срабатывает? `services.AddAuthorization` я добавил как в примере.

Comment: это хз, не дебажил такое. Может что то в логи пишется.

Comment: Покажите полностью startup.cs  у вас же наверняка https, а где настройки cors , https, hsts ?

Comment: @AK, спасибо. Дело было в том что наш сервис выдает кастомный Bearer токен... Пришлось писать свой вилосипед.

Comment: Было бы интересно взглянуть в познавательных целях. Не хотите вкратце показать в ответе?

Comment: @AK вот тут пример, возможно подскажите вдруг есть способ лучше чем я сделал https://gist.github.com/milovidov983/3f8292d87ac4f51142bfdccc5dc1ae4d

Comment: Не знаю, я с подобными задачами ещё не сталкивался, поэтому не представляю какие ещё возможны варианты. PS Handler пишется через "А", а не "Е", поправьте у себя.