# Регистрация и авторизация в asp.net Core + Angular 8

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, angular2, angular

вот уже добрые 5 дней мучаюсь и не могу найти руководство по авторизации в коре и онгуляре. Есло в коре я создаю все как надо, то когда дело доходит до стороны клиента, ничего не получается(( Люди добрые не подкините ли ссылку на руководство, которое выведет меня из этого темного леса и придаст ясности моей голове?(

Comment: Какие проблемы то? Вы ж ничего не написали.

Comment: @tym32167 В общем надо сделать соц сеть(новое тест задание у меня такое), решил начать с авторизации, нашел вроде как пример, но там проблема, апи в одном проекте, ангуляр во втором, если апи на коре я могу запустить через вс 2017, то как запустить ангуляровский проект не могу понять, начал спрашивать людей, мне пишут что так наоборот удобно, что сервер отдельно, клиент отдельно, а вот как клиента запустить(( проект о котором я говорю есть вот тут [ссылка](https://github.com/CodeMazeBlog/aspnetcore-jwt-auth/tree/aspnetcore-jwt-auth-part2-end)

Comment: @tym32167 Помогите разобраться плс Артем, вновь выручите как тогда с TotalPage'em  :)

Comment: Ну я с вебом не работаю особо, потому мне на слово не верьте, но если бы я писал подобное, то у меня бы агнуляр был бы отдельным приложением и собирался бы с помощью ноды, а asp.net core - отдельный проект, который собирается с помощью дотнета. Как только я бы это понял, я бы стал думать, какая должна быть авторизация, на куках, на токенах или что то типа oauth, причем что бы не выбрал, отдельно пришлось бы писать код для бекенда и отдельно для фронтенда.

Comment: Причем и руководства вам надо искать отдельно, то есть для ангуляра одно, для бекенда - другое, и в проекте уже их совмещать. То есть вот народа вам будет jwt аутентификацию делать, ищите руководства отдельно для аншуляра и бекенда.

Comment: Я когда то делал [jwt аутентификацию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/852085/179763) но там asp.net core 2, для новой версии я не имею понятия как такое делать.

Comment: @tym32167 да я нашел уже руководство, по ссылке которую я вам дал в сообщении выше как раз в итоге полуается 2 проекта с кором и ангуляром, Так же на другом форуме упомянали "ноду", что это нода?? впервые слышу:)

Comment: https://nodejs.org/en/ с помощью этого инструмента можно много чего делать, в том числе и билдить ангуляр проект в набор скриптов/хтмл, который уже можно выкладывать на сервер как готовый фронтенд билд.

Comment: @tym32167 сегодня буду тестить, спасибо!!

Comment: @tym32167 Перехожу в корневую папку проекта, запускаю ng serve --open, выдает сообщение "The serve command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found." :(

Comment: Чтобы запустить проект на ангуляре, надо сначала создать проект на аегуляре, потом перейти в папку этого проекта и там уже его запускать

Comment: @tym32167 В общем нашел инструкцию, последовал ей, выдавало ошибку. Затем, скачал проект по ссылке которую давал выше, запустил проект веб апи в вс2019, затем перешел в корневую папку проекта ангуляр, который работает в связке с проектом запущенным на вс, ввел npm install -g @angular/cli и затем запустил ng serve --open, и все заработало, ура! :)

Comment: В [доке](https://cli.angular.io/) на первой же картинке есть все, что нужно для создания проекта на ангуляре

Comment: @tym32167 да да, именно там я и читал, спасибо Артем!

Answer (score 2):

В общем покопавшись в интернете я нашел все же нужную информацию, Вот тут полное руководство о том, как настроить [серверную часть](https://code-maze.com/authentication-aspnetcore-jwt-1/)
, далее по [этой ссылке](https://code-maze.com/authentication-aspnetcore-jwt-2/) полная инструкция по настройке фронтенда на Angular.
Полностью готовый проект с сервером и клиентом [вот тут](https://github.com/CodeMazeBlog/aspnetcore-jwt-auth/tree/aspnetcore-jwt-auth-part2-end)
В комментариях этого вопроса есть достаточно инфы, чтобы разобраться с тем, что и как запускать(если вы такой же новичок как и я :) )