# Как заменить расширение AddJwtBearer при переходе на .NET Core 3.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

У меня есть следующий код который компилировался и работал в .NET Core 2.2:

```
  byte[] key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Constants.JWT_SECRET); 
        services.AddAuthentication(x =>
        {
            x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddJwtBearer(x =>
        {
            x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            x.SaveToken = true;
            x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                ValidateAudience = false
            };
        });
```

В .NET Core 3.0 я получаю следующую ошибку:

> Error CS1061  'AuthenticationBuilder' does not contain a definition for
>   'AddJwtBearer' and no accessible extension method 'AddJwtBearer'
>   accepting a first argument of type 'AuthenticationBuilder' could be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

при переходе в документацию:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.jwtbearerextensions.addjwtbearer?view=aspnetcore-2.2

не нахожу версии для 3.0

Как мне провести миграцию AddJwtBearer на Core 3.0?

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [How to replace AddJwtBearer extension in .NET Core 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7399611/5752652) от участника  [@shelbypereira](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1359155/shelbypereira).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58593240/

Answer (score 1):

Установите пакет [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer/), указав **версию 3.0.0**.

<sub>Использован свободный перевод ответа [How to replace AddJwtBearer extension in .NET Core 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7399611/5752652) от участника  [@Overlord](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2031447/overlord).</sub>