# C# WinForm Сделать выпадающий список последние использованные файлы(объекты)

Tags: c#

Использую такой код

```
private void CreateLastItemsToolStripMenu(string filename)
        {
            ToolStripMenuItem new_toolStripMenuItem = new ToolStripMenuItem();
            new_toolStripMenuItem.Text = filename;
            new_toolStripMenuItem.Click += new_toolStripMenuItem_click;
            this.lastItemsToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.AddRange(
                new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem[] { new_toolStripMenuItem });

            if (this.lastItemsToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Count > 10)
                this.lastItemsToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.RemoveAt(0);
        }
```

Вот если делать историю всего что использовалось, как ранее открытые вкладки в браузере, это тогда каждую удаленную вкладку надо в файл сохранять? Или в БД? Или еще есть варианты?

Comment: А в чем вопрос?

Comment: Не вопрос,а уже решение. С этим у меня проблем не возникло, решил поделиться решением.

Comment: Ты можешь отслеживать событие изменения выпадающего списка и заносить их в list

Comment: Если вы решите делиться знаниями в стиле вопрос/ответ -- то обратите внимание, что вопрос отдельно ("первый пост"), решение отдельно. На текущий момент как я понимаю, код должен уйти в ответ, а вопрос (из заголовка) следует более тщательно артикулировать. Мне например непонятно, в чём проблема только по заголовку. Пример можно посмотреть тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1142221/213987 Отредактируйте вопрос, дайте ответ отдельно.