# Как уведомить пользователя, если при регистрации нового пользователя выдаётся ошибка уникальности логина?

Tags: c#, postgresql, asp.net-core-mvc

Я новичок в ASP.NEC Core MVC и сейчас делаю первую программу на нём - простой мессенджер. У меня есть отдельный класс, который отправляет запросы в БД и обрабатывает ошибки этого же рода - `DBConnection`. Если я поймаю ошибку уникальности логина, например, то перехвачу её в catch. Как мне уведомить пользователя, если эта ошибка произошла? Например, отобразить окно с надписью "Пользователь с таким логином уже существует". Использую Npgsql - PostgreSQL.

Comment: [Документация](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#examine-register).

Answer (score 0):

Тебе надо сделать так:
Например у тебя метод регистрации

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Register(LoginModel details,
            string returnUrl) {
        if (ModelState.IsValid) {
            AppUser user = await userManager.FindByLoginAsync(details.Login);
            if (user != null) {
            ModelState.AddModelError(nameof(LoginModel.Login),
                "Invalid username ");
            }
            else
             {
               //Register user
             }
        }
        return View(details);
```

Если у тебя спа с реакт то [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/851781/Как-правильно-готовить-авторизацию-в-spa](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/851781/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%B2-spa)