# JWT-авторизация всегда возвращает 401 Unauthorized

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, jwt

Эндпоинт постоянно возвращает 401 Unauthorized. Использовал [этот](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/378374/is-there-a-light-jwt-token-in-aspnet-core-web-api.html) туториал.

```cs
[HttpGet]
[Authorize]
public async Task<ActionResult<User>> Get(HttpContext httpContext)
{
    return Ok();
}
```

Program.cs:

```cs
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using backend.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddAuthorization();

IConfigurationSection jwtConfig = builder.Configuration.GetSection("Jwt");
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer((options) =>
{
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidIssuer = jwtConfig.GetValue<string>("Issuer"),
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidAudience = jwtConfig.GetValue<string>("Audience"),
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        RequireExpirationTime = true,
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(File.ReadAllBytes(jwtConfig.GetValue<string>("Key")))
    };
});

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationContext>((options) => options.UseNpgsql(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
builder.Services.AddSingleton<EmailChecker>();

var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Код генератора токена:

```cs
[HttpPost("login")]
public ActionResult Login(UserLogin req)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    User user;

    try
    {
        user = context.Users.First((x) => x.Email == req.Email && x.Verified);
    }
    catch (InvalidOperationException)
    {
        return BadRequest("userNotFound");
    }

    if (!VerifyPasswordHash(req.Password, user.PasswordHash, user.PasswordSalt))
    {
        return BadRequest("invalidPassword");
    }

    return Ok(CreateToken(user));
}

private string CreateToken(User user)
{
    ClaimsIdentity claims = new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[]{
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Id.ToString()),
    });

    IConfigurationSection jwtConfig = cfg.GetSection("Jwt");

    SecurityTokenDescriptor desc = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
    {
        Subject = claims,
        IssuedAt = DateTime.UtcNow,
        Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(2),
        SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(privateKey), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature),
        Issuer = jwtConfig.GetValue<string>("Issuer"),
        Audience = jwtConfig.GetValue<string>("Audience"),
    };

    JwtSecurityTokenHandler jwtHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
    SecurityToken tok = jwtHandler.CreateToken(desc);

    return jwtHandler.WriteToken(tok);
}
```

Запрос к генератору токена:[image: 1]

Запрос к защищенному токеном эндпоинту: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: 401 это означает что ожидался HTTP заголовок `Authorization` от клиента (браузера) с данными авторизации, но не был получен сервером.

Comment: @aepot заголовок передан, и в правильном формате ("Authorization: Bearer ...")

Comment: Приведите пример запроса, его заголовков в вопросе. Приведите код, отправляющий запрос и передающий токен. Локализовать баг только по коду бэкенда, это как искать одно неизвестное в уравнении, где их два.

Comment: @aepot, обновил вопрос

Comment: А если `[Authorize]` убрать, работает?

Comment: @aepot да, работает

Comment: Когда то делал подобное, может быть ещё актуально https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/852085/179763

Answer (score 1):

По каким-то причинам ASP.NET Core отказывает в авторизации, если соединение не защищено. Удаление `app.UseHttpsRedirection()` решает проблему.